# Android PackageManger - NameNotFound Exception

Tags: android

I am using a `BroadcastReceiver` to register for package added event and as soon as I get that event I call package manager with getApplicationInfo to get more ifnormation about the package installed. At this time I receive namenoutfoundexception and I believe it is because the packagemanager has not updated the data and I got the event before it. how do I resolve this? Any ideas?

My code:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Launch the activity for showing reputation of application
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(ApplicationListViewActivity.this,AppViewActivity.class);

        //Next create the bundle and initialize it
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String pkgName = intent.getData().toString();
        //Add the parameters to bundle as 
        bundle.putString("pkgName",pkgName);
        //Add this bundle to the intent
        intent1.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent1);
}

try {
            ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(pkgName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

{//end up here}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pkgName` looks like this: `package: com.your.package.name`, all you need to do is remove the `package:`.

You can do it by this:

```
int pos = pkgName.indexOf(':');
if(pos>=0) {
    pkgName = pkgName.substring(pos + 1);
}
```

Happy coding.